# Right way to check an database insertion and rollback with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have here a code to insert the order of the customer in the `orders` table and insert the purchased products in that order in the `purchased_products` table. I want to check if the insertions were made, otherwise undo the changes with PDO `rollback()`. My code is:

```
$options = [
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
];    

try
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}", $USERNAME, $PASS, $options);
}

$connection->beginTransaction();

try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_value, order_date)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array
    (
        $user_id,
        $user['user_name'],
        $order_value,
        $date
    ));

    $id_of_respective_order = $connection->lastInsertId();
}
catch(PDOException $exception) 
{
    $connection->rollback();
    echo "<script>alert('An error occurred while completing your purchase. Please try again later.');</script>";
}

try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products (order_id, product_name, product_price, quantity)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
    {
        $query->execute(array
        (
            $id_of_respective_order,
            $product['product_name'],
            $product['product_price'],
            $product['quantity']
        ));
    }
}
catch(PDOException $exception) 
{
    $connection->rollback();
    echo "<script>alert('An error occurred while completing your purchase. Please try again later.');</script>";
}

$connection->commit();
```

Is this way safe? I use a transaction to lock the tables and `lastInsertId ()` to assign the ID of the order to the products that belongs to it. I check the insertions and if something went wrong undo the changes with `rollback()`. Is my checkout system well prepared and  totally safe?

Comment: do you escape all user input?

Comment: @SuperDJ Yes, all data present in session arrays have secure origin, direct from database, the only user input in my code is the quantity.

Comment: You have missed the `catch` block from the initial try/catch around the `new PDO()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sence to do all your inserts inside the same Try/Catch and then if the order insert or the order_item insert fails a single catch block will deal with the rollback and any cleanup/reporting that may be required.

The way you had it the order insert could fail and then the order_item insert would still try and run, possibly creating items without a owning order.

```
try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}", 
                          $USERNAME, $PASS);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e ) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$connection->beginTransaction();

try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders 
           (customer_id, customer_name, order_value, order_date)
           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array( $user_id,
                         $user['user_name'],
                         $order_value,
                         $date
                        )
                   );

    $id_of_respective_order = $connection->lastInsertId();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products 
                   (order_id, product_name, product_price, quantity)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
        $query->execute(array( $id_of_respective_order,
                               $product['product_name'],
                               $product['product_price'],
                               $product['quantity']
                              )
                       );
    }

    $connection->commit();

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $connection->rollBack();

    echo 'Order creation failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo "<script>alert('An error occurred while completing your purchase. Please try again later.');</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I would like to make a test exception. I changed the name of one of the tables for a non-existent but the code still ran and entered the data in another table. It should not have fallen into the catch? Maybe my PDO is not cathing exceptions. How to find this out?

Comment: Minor change check it out, maybe that will make some difference

Comment: Now is working! Thank you! But why the `$connection->commit();` is inside `try` and `$connection->beginTransaction();` is out? And I throwned the exception by changing the name of the second table to a non-existent. I've got the error message, but the order was inserted anyway in first table. How to prevent this?

Comment: I changed  ` $connection->rollback();` to `$connection->rollBack();` I missed the case spelling error before. Test again now

Comment: Also **just a quick sanity check** This database is using a database engine that supports transactions **isn't it** i.e. it is a INNODB database **RIGHT ???**

Comment: No, my hosting don't support INNODB. :/

Comment: **THEN YOU CANNOT USE TRANSACTIONS** The code will not generate errors but MYISAM databases do not support transactional processing. The beginTransaction/commit/rollBack just get ignored and every update gets committed instantly

Comment: Thank you, I will move to a host that supports INNODB.